# TestHost child components have undefined attributes

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm writing a simple unit test where I want to test that the "base" component of my application is defined.  It has two child components: 1) `story-outline`, 2) `story-dialog`.  However, Karma is complaining about missing dependencies in those child components.  I thought the whole point of declaring them in a test host component was to avoid this.  Maybe I'm doing it incorrectly or not understanding how it all works.  I've been following the unit testing documentation on the official Angular 2 site.

The spec import statements are all of the dependencies for the AppComponent.  I shouldn't need to include the dependencies for the other two components that  I declared in the `beforeEach`, right?

**Current spec**

```
import {Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ViewContainerRef, ViewEncapsulation, DebugElement} from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService} from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';
import {StoryDialog} from '...';
import {StoryDialogService} from '...';
import {AppComponent} from '...;
import {StoryComponent} from '...';
import {TestBed, ComponentFixture, async} from '@angular/core/testing';

let testHost: AppComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
let de: DebugElement;
let el: HTMLElement;

let translateServiceStub = {

};

let storyDialogServiceStub = {
    storyDialog: StoryDialog
};

describe('Component:App', () => {
    beforeEach( async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [],
            declarations: [AppComponent, StoryDialog, StoryComponent],
            providers: [
                {provide: TranslateService, useValue: translateServiceStub},
                {provide: StoryDialogService, useValue: storyDialogServiceStub}
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));    

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        testHost = fixture.componentInstance;
        de = fixture.debugElement;
    });

    it('should be defined', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(testHost).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

**Class to test**

```
import {Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ViewContainerRef, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService} from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';
import {StoryDialogService} from '...';
import {StoryDialog} from '...';    

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
        <story-outline></story-outline>
        <story-dialog></story-dialog>            
    `,
  styles: [require('./app.component.scss')],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(StoryDialog)
  storyDialog: StoryDialog;

  private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService,
              private storyDialogService: StoryDialogService,
              viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    this.viewContainerRef = viewContainerRef;

    translate.addLangs(['en-US']);
    this.translate.setDefaultLang('en-US');
    this.translate.use('en-US');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.storyDialogService.storyDialog= this.storyDialog;
  }
}
```

**Stack trace focus**

```
18 11 2016 11:32:03.150:WARN [reporter]: SourceMap position not found for trace: Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "bs-modal" ("<div bsModal [config]="{backdrop:'static', show:false, keyboard:false}" [ERROR ->]#storyDialog="bs-modal"
     (onShow)="onShowHandler($event)" (onHide)="onHideHandler($event)"
 "): StoryDialog@0:72
Can't bind to 'config' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("<div bsModal [ERROR ->][config]="{backdrop:'static', show:false, keyboard:false}" #storyDialog="bs-modal"
     (onShow)"): StoryDialog@0:13
The pipe 'translate' could not be found ("         </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <div class="story-heading">[ERROR ->]{{'STORY_HEADING' | translate }}</div>
              <div class="story-messages" *ngFor="let msg "): StoryDialog@15:47 in http://localhost:9876/base/spec-bundle.js?49d17eb052faf1cac3d7948dc8d95dee63357e3d (line 52498)
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve] including the component under test and the full error message.

Comment: I need to obfuscate the code so the full error stack may not be possible... I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Creating the minimal example should give you sufficient cover, it's unlikely that any business logic is relevant.